# How do you append a single item to a jQuery UI autocomplete resultset dropown?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is there a way to append **one** item to the end of an autocomplete dropdown that will have from 1-5 items?  I used `open` but because I append a spinner to the dropdown on load, it doesn't work well.

jQuery:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    response([{loading: true}]);
    return $.ajax({
      url: "/search",
      timeout: 10000,
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        query: request.term
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var results;
        results = [];
        results = $.map(data, function(result) {
          return {
            label: result.name,
          };
        });
        return response(results);
      }
    });
  }
  //open doesn't work because I have a spinning effect that opens a dropdown
  //when the search is loading.
  //open: function() {
  //  alert('test');
  //}
})
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  if(item.loading) {
    return $( "<li id='spinner'></li>" )
      .appendTo( ul );
  }
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: You always want to append one item, no matter what the user searched for?

Comment: I would like to put the number of items in the result set in the text of the last appended item.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to just `push` whatever item you want onto the results list before you send it to the `response` callback:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        response([{loading: true}]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/search",
            timeout: 10000,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                query: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var results = $.map(data, function(result) {
                    return {
                        label: result.name,
                    };
                });

                results.push({ label: "My Custom Item" });
                response(results);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/m3MGH/1/